# Bijective single variable real functions which does not commute under composition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, examples-counterexamples

Are there bijective single variable real functions which does not commute under composition?  I believe it does because of permutations in discrete case, but I am not able to find it.

Comment: Are you asking if there exist $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $g\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f\circ g\neq g\circ f$?

Comment: Yes, with both functions bijective.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x\mapsto x^3$ and $x\mapsto 2x$.

Comment: thank you. In fact, I guess I could not think any more.  I tried your first example and failed. Bed time. Thanks again

Comment: @jaare You're welcome.